# Relate $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i c_j f(x_i, x_j) \geq 0$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i c_j \theta(x_i) \theta(x_j) \geq 0$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have the following
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i c_j f(x_i, x_j) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i c_j \theta(x_i) \theta(x_j) \geq 0
$$(note that $f$ is a symmetric function if that is relevant)
My goal is to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i c_j f(x_i, x_j) \theta(x_i) \theta(x_j)  \geq 0$. Is it possible to use the two inequalities I have found above to show it?

Comment: your second inequality does not say anything because it's:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\theta(x_i)\right)^2\geq 0,$$
so my hunch is your conclusion do not necessarily follow.

Comment: @dezdichado How can you ignore the $f$ function? I mean shouldn't its presence in the inequality change something?

Comment: I am not ignoring $f$ but it's given right? Now you have the freedom to choose $\theta(x)$ however you want. If your implication is true, then it must necessarily follow that it should be true for $\textit{any}$ choice of $\theta$ and this is a very strong statement. I'd be surprised if it holds.

Comment: @dezdichado I used this (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/322222) to show the one inequality and the fact that I assume $f$ is a so-called kernel which gives a positive-definite matrix(or in other words satisfy the inequality). Is your last comment referring to the final inequality or? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @dezdichado You were doubting about the statement. In fact it holds !

Comment: nice very simple as it turned out. I had recently used the very same fact for my work and I don't know why it didn't click for me.

Answer (score 3):

You surely know the matrix form :

$$\forall C\ne0, \ \ C^TFC \ge 0 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \  \ C^TGC \ge 0,\tag{1}$$

where

- $C$ is the column vector with entries $c_i$,
- $F$ is the matrix with entries $F_{i,j}=f(x_i,x_j)$,
- $G$ is the matrix with entries $G_{i,j}=\theta(x_i)\theta(x_j)$.

(1) means that matrices $F$ and $G$ are (semi)definite positive.

The result you are looking for is an immediate consequence of the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) saying that the Hadamard product of two positive definite matrices is itself positive definite.

Recall: Hadamard product of two matrices is plainly their entrywise product: $c_{ij}=a_{ij}b_{ij}.$

**Edit :**

1. Matrix $G$ of your second quadratic form is very particular: it is a rank 1 matrix.
2. There is a connection between Hadamard product and Kronecker product (which is not given in the Wikipedia article) if you happen to know the latter product ; see for example [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379599001871).

Comment: Please, say if my answer is understandable.